# How do I send basic credentials (id, password) to a webservice in the soap header?

Tags: vb.net, soap, webclient, networkcredentials

I have a new webservice that I'm setting up to call, the provider tells me that I need to include basic credentials in the soap header, something I haven't done previously.  Here's the example they provided:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns: soapenv = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>
       <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
           <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
               <wsse:Username>userid</wsse:Username>
               <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">xxxxxx</wsse:Password>
           </wsse:UsernameToken>
       </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
       blah blah blah
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I've created my proxy class by referencing the wsdl and xsd files they provided.  After instantiating an instance of the proxy, I added a `NetworkCredential` to the service instance, specified to not use default credentials, and pointed it at example.com (because I don't have access to the real web service yet).

```
        osvc.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("xxxxx", "yyyyy")
        osvc.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        osvc.Url = "http://www.example.com"
```

Inspecting the contents of the service instance does show the new credentials with the id and password.

Started up Fiddler and called the service method.  The call failed of course, since example.com is going to return html, not xml, but I wanted to inspect the request that was sent.  The id and password were not in the message:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      blah blah blah
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

What am I doing wrong or not understanding?  How do I get my id and password sent in the soap header?

Comment: To be clear - are you receiving a 401 (using the real user/pass/domain)?

Comment: @pep, No, I am not sending (yet) to the real web service, I am doing some pre-testing by sending to example.com and expected (hoped?) to see my id and password in the request (captured with Fiddler), so I could confirm (or not) whether I'm constructing my request correctly, so when I do gain connectivity to the actual web service, I can proceed more quickly with dev and testing.